# Как в консольном приложение использовать класс Bitmap?

Tags: c#

Можно ли в консольном приложение использовать [Bitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx)? Если да, то как?
Мне нужно, чтобы программа открывала изображение по указному пути и выводила ширину и высоту в консоль. 
Все примеры, которые я находил, были только для WindowsForms.

Comment: Конечно можно .

Answer (score 10):

Добавляете reference на `System.Drawing` в ваш проект, и используете класс `Bitmap` как обычно.

Answer (score 0):

В ссылках проекта указываете `System.Drawing`, `System.Windows.Forms`, затем загружаете битмат в bitmap, получаете контекст окна консоли и рисуете в ней свой битмап.

Comment: Как я понял, ТС не нужно ничего рисовать, требуется только вывести ширину и высоту, поэтому System.Windows.Forms не нужен.